# How to reset a region of a sprite

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I created a sprite which contains 10 numbers (0-9). With this sprite I want to create a basic score. This score counts every time the user touches the screen. Unfortunately it doesn't work, so I need your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why sprite-sheet of numbers ?

You should use [BitmapFont](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bitmap-fonts) if you're not using using [scene-2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) module of LibGDX.

1. BitmapFont

   ```
   BitmapFont font= new BitmapFont();
   String score="0";
   ```

   And Inside `render()` method

   ```
   font.draw(batch,score,100,100);
   ```

   Whenever you want to change score

   ```
   int scoreValue = Integer.parseInt(score);
   scoreValue++;
   score=String.valueOf(scoreValue);
   ```
2. If you're using scene2d, create [Label](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#label) for score and and to `Stage`. After that stage is responsible for drawing, You only have to update `Label` text.

   ```
   label.setText("new-value");
   ```

---

You can also use your own approach but I don't think so that is good way.

- You can create a `Group` having size depending upon digit in your score.
- Count total number of digit in your score like if digit if 3
- get number from from sprite-sheet and place in appropriate position.

From score to particular number if digit is three :

```
int i = score / 100;
int j = score % 100 / 10;
int k = score % 10;
```

Each time remove this group and create new one or remove all actors from that group and add new digit Actor.

Comment: Thank you! I've implemented a score but no I have another problem: if the score gets over 9, the two numbers have a big gap to each other but I don't want this space. It looks like: 1       1 for eleven but it has to look like: 11, so without huge space between.  Hope you can help me.

Comment: why are you not going with my suggestion, any specific reason.. ? Anyway why some space between 1 and 1, may be 1 digit is not totally trimmed.